# Can't grab a certain item from a webpage

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, css-selectors, simple-html-dom

I've written a script in ***php*** to scrape the ***phone number*** and ***email address*** from a webpage. When I execute my following script, I get the ***phone number*** but in case of ***email address*** I get this piece of text ***Email***.

The two fields I'm after are located under this title `Sterling Systems & Control Inc.` in that webpage.

[This is the site address](https://us.kompass.com/a/grinding-machinery-and-equipment-for-the-food-industry/49030/)

My attempt of getting them so far:

```
<?php
    include "simple_html_dom.php";
    function curlGet($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $results = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $dom->load($results);
        return $dom;
    }
    $data = curlGet('https://us.kompass.com/a/grinding-machinery-and-equipment-for-the-food-industry/49030/');
    foreach($data->find("div.list-buttons-container") as $item){
        $phone = $item->find("#freePhone--US947504",0)->value;
        $email = $item->find("[class='coordonneesItemLink'] .coordinate-item-text",1)->innertext;
        echo "{$phone} {$email}<br>";
    }
?>
```

Output I'm having at this moment (instead of email address I get only the below text):

```
+1 8156250852 Email
```

This is how they are visible in that site:
[image]

Comment: Well the phone number is contained in the HTML code … whereas the e-mail address doesn’t seem to be, that button opens only a contact form.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The email address button opens a dialog that allows you to send an email to the related product owner (or whatever it is). The email address is most probably stored on a database and retrieved only when you actually send the email through the form.

If the email address is not anywhere in the page, you can't actually grab it.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Alberto. What If I fill in the form and wish to grab the response? Is it possible that way?

Comment: As I said, the email address is not visible (meaning, it's not written somewhere in clear text) in the html, so you can't grab it. There is the "company id" on a field (in this case US947504), this refers to an id on a database, that will link to the email address to let the script send the company an email.